# How do I fill in the @me parameter in Google Tasks API calls?

Tags: api, google-tasks-api

I am trying to make a call to the Google Tasks API [(link)](https://developers.google.com/tasks/reference/rest/v1/tasklists/list#http-request). There is a parameter in the URL call @me but I am not sure how to fill it?

I went ahead and created a userID for a project where I enabled Google Tasks API, and I tried to use that userID, but it does not seem work.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to replace the word `me`. When it should be done, as in the [get](https://developers.google.com/tasks/reference/rest/v1/tasklists/get) method, it is indicated like this: `{word}`. In addition, it is indicated as: `Path parameters`.

For instance, GET: `https://tasks.googleapis.com/tasks/v1/users/@me/lists/{tasklist}`.